# Descartes Robot Path Editor

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a Robot Path Editor in [Descartes Sneak Peek](https://youtu.be/cZxt00uoyBo?t=18) video demo. I saw robot_path_editor_gui.rviz at the upper left corner of the video. However, I cannot find a link related to it with google.
Though, I do find an interesting [Cartesian Path Planner Plug-in for MoveIt](http://wiki.ros.org/moveit_cartesian_plan_plugin).

I would like to create a list of Robot Path Editors:

1. fermi - Cartesian Path Planner MoveIt Plug-in, [source code](https://github.com/ros-industrial-consortium/fermi), [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/moveit_cartesian_plan_plugin)
2. ... please help providing Robot Path Editors

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227721/descartes-robot-path-editor/) by [Yishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26015/yishin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik, that UI is a proprietary component that came out of a ROS-I project. It is unlikely to be made open-source. It's also not part of the descartes packages.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-03-31**:
:/ Ok, I added this info on the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/descartes#Applications).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you installed and tried the packages that that video is demoing ?
http://wiki.ros.org/descartes

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-02-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26015/yishin/) on 2016-02-28**:
@gvdhoorn, you clarified my question, thanks. -Yishin

**Comment by [Yishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26015/yishin/) on 2016-02-28**:
@nickw, I installed descartes, and tried it with ROS-I training exercise. There is a [demo_descartes](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_training/tree/59865c84700cd998d8fd822a6b74bc2630a0ce6e/training/ref/demo_descartes/src). This is not one of those cool videos, but still pretty cool.